# glDrawArrays vs glDrawElements w/Texture mapping

Tags: c++, opengl

I was experimenting over the weekend with a simple Waveform OBJ importer I developed for school. While doing that I read about glDrawArrays and glDrawElements and how the latter outperforms the former by keeping vertices in buffer for easy access rather than redrawing them. I developed simple algorithms to sort my vertex, texture and normal arrays to use both. However, when using gDE, I can't associate the same vertex to a different normal and/or texture since it uses the same index for all 3 buffers. Therefore, vertices that are drawn upon a different polygon keep the same texture they get in the first appearance on the OBJ. That can be solved by writing the same vertex n-times as necessary in the buffer with the normal/texture values they need. However, this solution turns the final buffer result into the same buffers that would be used for gDA. So, my question is: Is there still any performance advantage? Or is there a different solution to this inconvenience?

Comment: Since a vertex is the union of all attributes (like normals, texCoords or positions, which are unfortunately called *"vertex"* in GL), you won't get around introducing some duplicate vertices (or rather vertices with duplicate positions ;)). But for a usual model you should still end up with much fewer distinct vertices than indices, since you only need to dulicate vertices at texture seams (when texCoords differ) or hard egdes (when normals differ). So for reasonable geometry this is still the recommended approach.

Comment: @ChristianRau Hadn't thought of that. It apparently doesn't work for the model I used for testing, but I'll keep this in mind to redesign my algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest approach is to just create a new OpenGL vertex for each unique index-triple in the OBJ file, which can be realized quite easily by filling a hash table mapping OBJ-index-triple to OpenGL-index while reading and creating a new vertex (with the attributes gathered from the OBJ file) whenever the index-triple is not in the hash table yet. But there are indeed cases where you will have to duplicate nearly every vertex, though those are rather artificial or simlified cases (like a cube, or maybe an object having a different texture mapping for each face).

Answer (score 1):

> I can't associate the same vertex to a different normal and/or texture since it uses the same index for all 3 buffers.

You fell for a common misconception, namely that "vertex" equals "position". *This is not the case!* A vertex is the whole combination of position, normal, texture coordinate and all the other attributes you use. You change one of the attribute's values and you get a different vertex. So what you have to do is generating the actual vertices of your model from the faces in the OBJ file.

Unfortunately many people fell for the misconception that "vertex" == "position" and so you can find many file formats and specifications that wrongly substitute position with vertex. For example in the wavefront OBJ format positions are defined with `v` instead of the more sensible `vp`.

The distrinction between the mathematical object called "vertex" and a position becomes very apparent in modern OpenGL where you have to supply a *vertex shader* that takes arbitrary, generic attributes as vertex input, of which none of them actually needs to be a position and can create clip space position in an arbitrary way from the input.